# New to Spark, mapping with graphx graphs - NullPointerException

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, spark-graphx, map-function

My goal is to count triangles in multiple subgraphs from a common full graph. The subgraph is defined by a constant set of nodes + a node from an RDD[Long]. I'm new to spark/graphx, so this may be an improper use of map. **The code I'm sharing will reproduce my error.**

To start, I have a subgraph of a full graph declared as shown below

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd._
import org.apache.spark.graphx._
val nodes: RDD[(VertexId, String)] = sc.parallelize(Array((3L, "3"), (7L, "7"), (5L, "5"), (2L, "2"),(4L,"4")))
val vertices: RDD[Edge[String]] = sc.parallelize(Array(Edge(3L, 7L, "a"), Edge(3L, 5L, "b"), Edge(2L, 5L, "c"), Edge(5L, 7L, "d"), Edge(2L, 7L, "e"),Edge(4L,5L,"f")))
val graph: Graph[String,String] = Graph(nodes, vertices, "z")

val baseNodes: Array[Long] = Array(2L,5L,7L)    
val subgraph = graph.subgraph(vpred = (vid,attr)=> baseNodes contains vid)
```

Then I declare an RDD[Long] of other nodes from the graph.

```
val testNodes: RDD[Long] = sc.parallelize(Array(3L,4L))
```

I want to add each testNode to the subgraph and count the triangles present at testNode.

```
val triangles: RDD[(Long,Int)] = testNodes.map{ newNode =>
  val newNodes: Array[Long] = baseNodes :+ newNode
  val newSubgraph = graph.subgraph(vpred = (vid,attr)=> newNodes contains vid)
  (newNode,findTriangles(7L,newSubgraph))
}
triangles.foreach(x=>x.toString)
```

My findTriangles works fine if I call it outside of the map function.

```
def findTriangles(id:Long,subgraph:Graph[String,String]): Int = {
  val triCounts = subgraph.triangleCount().vertices
  val count:Int = triCounts.filter{case(item,count)=> {item.toInt == id}}.map{case(item,count)=>count}.first
  count
}
val triangles = findTriangles(7L,subgraph) //1
```

But when I run my map function to calculate triangles, I get a NullPointerException. I think the problem is in using my graph val inside the mapping function. Is that the issue? Is there a way to workaround this?

Comment: You can't work on an `'RDD` within another `RDD`. This is not limited to `GraphX` -- it's a limitation on `RDD`s and since `GraphX` is built on `RDD`s, well -- that's your issue. Long story short -- the executors know nothing about your other `RDD`s, hence the `NPE`. In general, the way around this would be to do a join -- I haven't looked deeply enough into what you are trying to do, but that's the general idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the issue should be the baseNodes variable. Variables that are declared locally, such as baseNodes in your example, are only visible in the Spark driver, not in the executors that actually execute transformations and actions. To avoid the NullPointerException, you need to parallelize any variable that you'll need in the transformations (like map) that are executed on the executors. As an alternative, if the variable you have is read-only, you can broadcast that variable to executors using the broadcast construct in Spark. In your case, it seems that baseNodes doesn't get modified within the map operation, so it's a good candidate to be broadcast instead of parallelized.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Between your answer and David Griffin's comment I was able to figure out my problems. Broadcasting solves the issues with non-RDD variables, but since a graph in GraphX is built on RDDs, they cannot be accessed inside another map function. It seems like graphx was built to scale on a single large graph in memory, rather than spreading copies of the same graph to multiple executors. Since my graph isn't obscenely huge, I ditched graphx and store the graph as Arrays and Maps and implement my own triangleCount, allowing me to broadcast the graph